# Sorbet - concrete type when inheriting from generic class

Tags: ruby, sorbet

How can I specify `String` for the generic type?

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0A%0Aclass%20NameList%20%3C%20Array%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(names%3A%20T%3A%3AArray%5BString%5D).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(names)%0A%20%20%20%20names.each%20%7B%20%7Cn%7C%20self%20%3C%3C%20n%7D%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(String)%7D%0A%20%20def%20csv%0A%20%20%20%20(map%20%7B%20%7Cn%7C%20n.join('%2C')%20%7D).join(%22%5Cn%22)%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%0Anl%20%3D%20NameList.new(%5B'Bruce'%2C%20'Clark'%2C%20'Peter'%5D)%0A%0A%23%20Output%20length%20of%20first%20name.%0Aputs(nl.first%26.size)%20%20%23%20String%23size%0Aputs(nl.first%26.sizee)%20%20%23%20misspelled%20size%20-%20should%20be%20an%20error%0A)

```
# typed: strict


class NameList < Array
  extend T::Sig

  sig {params(names: T::Array[String]).void}
  def initialize(names)
    names.each { |n| self << n}
  end

  sig {returns(String)}
  def csv
    (map { |n| n.join(',') }).join("\n")
  end
end


nl = NameList.new(['Bruce', 'Clark', 'Peter'])

# Output length of first name.
puts(nl.first&.size)  # String#size
puts(nl.first&.sizee)  # misspelled size - should be an error

# Sorbet-Static output:
# editor.rb:4: Type Elem declared by parent Array must be re-declared in NameList https://srb.help/5036
#      4 |class NameList < Array
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#     https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/master/rbi/core/array.rbi#L350: Elem declared in parent here
#      350 |  Elem = type_member(:out)
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# Errors: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```rb
Elem = type_member(fixed: String)
```

Re-declaring the parent's type member is already obligatory (which you can see in the error message on your code snippet, which says `Type Elem declared by parent Array must be re-declared in NameList`) and re-declaring it with the `fixed:` parameter allows that type parameter to be specified as a concrete type.

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0A%0Aclass%20NameList%20%3C%20Array%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20Elem%20%3D%20type_member(fixed%3A%20String)%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(names%3A%20T%3A%3AArray%5BString%5D).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(names)%0A%20%20%20%20names.each%20%7B%20%7Cn%7C%20self%20%3C%3C%20n%7D%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Breturns(String)%7D%0A%20%20def%20csv%0A%20%20%20%20(map%20%7B%20%7Cn%7C%20n.join('%2C')%20%7D).join(%22%5Cn%22)%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%0Anl%20%3D%20NameList.new(%5B'Bruce'%2C%20'Clark'%2C%20'Peter'%5D)%0A%0A%23%20Output%20length%20of%20first%20name.%0Aputs(nl.first%26.size)%20%20%23%20String%23size%0Aputs(nl.first%26.sizee)%20%20%23%20misspelled%20size%20-%20should%20be%20an%20error%0A)

```rb
# typed: strict

class NameList < Array
  extend T::Sig

  Elem = type_member(fixed: String)

  sig {params(names: T::Array[String]).void}
  def initialize(names)
    names.each { |n| self << n}
  end

  sig {returns(String)}
  def csv
    (map { |n| n.join(',') }).join("\n")  # Method `join` does not exist on String
  end
end


nl = NameList.new(['Bruce', 'Clark', 'Peter'])

# Output length of first name.
puts(nl.first&.size)
puts(nl.first&.sizee)  # Method `sizee` does not exist on String
```